# Mocking a method which input is a list

Tags: java, mockito

I have the following code:

```
    sshCPList.add(new SSHParameter("ssh root@io1", "Password:", "(yes/no)?"));
    sshCPList.add(new SSHParameter(rootpwd, rootPrompt, null));
    sshCPList.add(new SSHParameter("ssh root@io1", "Password:", "(yes/no)?"));
    sshCPList.add(new SSHParameter(rootpwd, rootPrompt, null));
    if(!ssh2.sendSshShellCommandToUnknownHost(sshCPList)){
        theLogger.error("Failed to Authorize the PMF function to login as root");
        result = false;
    }
```

I want to define the following:

```
when(ssh2.sendSshShellCommandToUnknownHost(*a specific List which contains the four SSHParameter object or has 4 items or sonmething*).thenReturn(false);
```

The problem is I can not define that List as a proper input.

Any advice or solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eq(T value)` where `value` is that specific list.

Something like:

```
List<SSHParameter> expectedList = prepareExpectedList();
when(ssh2.sendSshShellCommandToUnknownHost(eq(expectedList)).thenReturn(false)
```

`prepareExpectedList();` returns a list that is `equals` to the input that you are going to supply in the test.

see http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Matchers.html

Answer (score 2):

In order to generate a custom `Matcher` you can use:

```
private static class MyListMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher<List<SSHParameter>> {

    private List<SSHParameter> expectedList;

    private MyListMatcher (List<SSHParameter> expectedList) {
        this.expectedList= expectedList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object obj) {
        List<SSHParameter> listToMatch = (List<SSHParameter>) obj;
        boolean result = true;// check whatever you want between listToMatch and expectedList (size, elements etc.);
        return result;
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
 when(ssh2.sendSshShellCommandToUnknownHost(argThat(new MyListMatcher(expectedList))).thenReturn(false);
```